# Class<T> not accepting ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am migrating existing code to a superclass/subclass situation. see below.

**METHOD IN PARENT CLASS:**

```
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> makeRequest(HttpMethod method, String endpoint, HttpEntity<?> request, Class<T> responseType) {
        //DO stuff here
    }
```

In the sub-class there is a call to the makeRequest() above.

```
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyOtherClass>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyOtherClass>>() {};
    ResponseEntity<List<MyOtherClass>> response = makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET,uriComponents.toUriString(), request, typeRef);
```

But the **last argument** seems to be causing a mismatch in the signature. Eclipse says this.

*"The method makeRequest(HttpMethod, String, HttpEntity, Class) in the type ParentWS is not applicable for the arguments (HttpMethod, String, HttpEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference>)"*

I don't understand why, the parent method signature says any class of any type. All other sub-classes are simply calling calling the parent method with **String.class**, like this.

```
response = makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET, healthCheckUrlEndpoint, request, String.class);
```

But why is **ParameterizedTypeReference>() {}** causing an issue?
I never worked with ParameterizedTypeReference before, its complete new to me. Please advise.

Comment: Simply put, a `ParameterizedTypeReference` is not a `Class`.  What `Class` were you intending to pass?  Was it `List<MyOtherClass>`?  If so, why not just pass that?

Answer (score 0):

Us I understend thte fourth parameter is Class type. Try `typeRef.getClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, method signature says `Class` as in `java.lang.Class`, so you should use `typeRef.getClass()` to pass instance of typeRef's class instead of instance of `ParametrizedClassReference`.

That would not work though.

`makeRequest` is supposed to return `ResponseEntity<T>`. What exactly is **T** will be inferred by Java compiler based on method parameters. If you change last parameter to `typeRef.getClass()` then Java will expect method to return `ResponseEntity<ParametrizedClassReference<List<MyOtherClass>>`.

I am going to do a wild guess here. Your `makeRequest` looks like wrapper for `RestTemplate.exchange()`, so maybe use overloaded version of `exchange()` which actually accepts `ParameterizedTypeReference`?

You might want to create overloaded version of `makeRequest` to accept `ParameterizedTypeReference` as well.

Comment: I created the overloaded method before, but the logic in both versions of makeRequest() is the same. only difference is that last parameter. Hence I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

From method definition:-

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> makeRequest(HttpMethod method, String endpoint, HttpEntity<?> request, Class<T> responseType);
```

Compiler expects generic type `Class<T>` as parameter. But you tried with different generic type `ParametrizedClassReference<T>` as argument. Hence it won't compile.

I assume internally the `makeRequest` method calls one of `RestTemplate#exchange` method. Change argument type of `ParametrizedClassReference<T>` to `Class<T>` for compilation to work. For example:-

```
Class<? extends List> classes = (new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>()).getClass();
ResponseEntity<List<MyOtherClass>> response = makeRequest(HttpMethod.GET,uriComponents.toUriString(), request, classes);
```

Comment: Actually the method in which this request is being made is getOtherClass and it returns a List<MyOtherClass>. I need to make this request to get the  List<MyOtherClass>.

Comment: Understood. @Faiyet perhaps (new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>()).getClass() statement will do. I have updated my example above